# How to refactor this if-else condition to make it cleaner and more efficient?

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

I have this piece of code as an Azure function app and I would like to know how can I best handle this `if else` part.

There are like 100 Project with different customer name.

What is the best way to do it?

If one can show me with an example.

```
string customerName = string.Empty;
foreach( var doc in result )
{
    var data =(JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( doc.ToString() );
    if( (string)data["Project"] == "HPD_Oid" )
    {
        customerName = "OPPO";
    }
    else if( (string)data["Project"] == "HPD_Oreal" )
    {
        customerName = "RealMe";
    }
    else
    {
        customerName = "OnePlus";
    }
    string partitionkeyValue = string.Concat( (string)data["class"], "|", (string)data["Project"], "|", customerName );
    data.Add( new JProperty( "PartitionKey", partitionkeyValue ) );
```

Read customer values:

```
CustomerSection customer = GetConfiguration( context.FunctionAppDirectory, "CustomerSection.json" );
```

Get config Value:

```
private static CustomerSection GetConfiguration( string basePath, string fileName )
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .SetBasePath( basePath )
                   .AddJsonFile( fileName, optional: false )
                   .Build();
            var customerNameOutput = new CustomerSection();
            config.GetSection( "ProjectCustomerMapping" ).Bind( customerNameOutput );
            return customerNameOutput;
        }

public class CustomerSection
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> CustomerName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like your solution is working. If you want to improve your code, the [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) page would be a better fit.

Comment: "how can I best handle this if else part" - what specific _problem_ do you have with your current solution? how _exactly_ do you want to improve it? what's your definition of "better"? you oughta be a bit more specific about your goals

Comment: if you really have 100 cases use something like Replace Conditional Dispatcher with Command - https://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/conditionDispatcherWithCommand.html

Comment: yes its works fine. I am looking to optimize my code as i have 100 different project name and each project name will have different customer. As by above code I have to put If else 100 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a bunch of extension methods for `IDictionary<K, V>` like this:

```
public static class IDictionaryExt
{
    public static Func<K, V> Map<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> source, Func<V> @default)
    {
        return key => (key == null || !source.ContainsKey(key)) ? @default() : source[key];
    }
}
```

I can use this like so:

```
Func<string, string> projectCustomerNameMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "HPD_Oid", "OPPO" },
    { "HPD_Oreal", "RealMe" }
}.Map(() => "OnePlus");
```

Then your code becomes:

```
string customerName = projectCustomerNameMapping((string)data["Project"]);
```

Comment: why am i getting dictionary<string,string> does not contain a definition for Map and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type Dictionary<string, string>

Comment: Because you have to implement his ```Map``` extension method in a static class. You can read more about extension methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: if I do that in a static class I get error on Func<string, string>projectCustomerNameMapping as cannot declare instance member in static class. should I just make it as static Func<>...

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint - I've edited the answer so that you can copy, paste, and use the extension method.

Answer (score 7):

Simple, use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> projectCustomerNameMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "HPD_Oid", "OPPO" },
    { "HPD_Oreal", "RealMe" }
};
```

And then use a lookup:

```
if (!projectCustomerNameMapping.TryGetValue((string)data["Project"], out customerName))
{
    // if the value wasn't found in the dictionary, use the default
    customerName = "OnePlus";
}
```

[TryGetValue docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-5.0)

Comment: +1, although I would add that the contents of the mapping should probably be moved to a database or config file.

Comment: @Taemyr I 100% agree.

Comment: how do i implement this as suggested by @Taemyr .i.e. how can we read by a config file

Comment: @ZzzSharePoint you could maybe create a JSON file and read that into a static dictionary, or a dictionary in a singleton class at application start. Without knowing more about your project, it's difficult to advise what the best option is.

Comment: hi, as far I see its best to read a json file with project and customer as Key value pair. Please see the updated question, as how I am trying to read. If this can completed with your code as reading from json instead of hardcoded dictionary